# gnuplot: force y2 axis tics on y tics position

Tags: gnuplot

inspired from the set link in another answer i want to plot a graph and show different scale axis.

```
set grid mytics
set xrange[1:5]  
set yrange[0:3]
set y2range[0:30]
set xlabel "a"   
set ylabel "b"  
set ytics 
set y2label "c"
set mytics 2

ca = 0.05
cb = 0.5

f(x) = sin(x*pi/180)*cb *1000
i(x) = asin(x/1000 / cb )/pi*180
set link y2 via f(y) inverse i(y)

pl asin(ca /x)/pi*180 title "a"
```

it draws the plot and the axis as expected but what i want is that the tics on the y2 axis are exact on the ytics (although they will be non round numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to put e.g. `6` equally distributed tics on an axis (like it would be done with `set my2tics 7`). But you can add the tics manually because you know the function range.

First you need to clear all automatic `y2tics` with

```
set y2tics (f(0))
```

And then you can set all minor and major tics in a loop:

```
do for [i=0:6] {
    set y2tics add (f(i/2.0))
    set y2tics add ('' f(i/2.0 + 0.25) 1)
}
```

Note, that looping with a float increment doesn't work.

So your complete script looks like this:

```
reset
set grid mytics
set xrange[1:5]  
set yrange[0:3]
set y2range[0:30]
set xlabel "a"   
set ylabel "b"  
set ytics nomirror
set y2label "c"
set mytics 2

ca = 0.05
cb = 0.5

f(x) = sin(x*pi/180)*cb *1000
i(x) = asin(x/1000 / cb )/pi*180
set link y2 via f(y) inverse i(y)

set format y2 '%.2f'
set y2tics (f(0)) # clear all automatic y2tics
do for [i=0:6] {
    set y2tics add (f(i/2.0))
    set y2tics add ('' f(i/2.0 + 0.25) 1)
}

pl asin(ca /x)/pi*180 title "a"
```

with the result:

[image]

There is a way to set the `y2tics` independent of the `yrange` as long as the number of major tics is known. First you plot with the `unknown` terminal, after which you can access the `yrange` value as the variables `GPVAL_Y_MIN` and `GPVAL_Y_MAX`. Unfortunately, one cannot access the number of tics of an axis:

```
...
set link y2 via f(y) inverse i(y)

set terminal push # save current terminal
set terminal unknown
pl asin(ca /x)/pi*180 title "a"

num_tics = 7
set format y2 '%.2f'
set y2tics (f(GPVAL_Y_MIN)) # clear all automatic y2tics
Y0 = GPVAL_Y_MIN
DY = (GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN)/(num_tics-1)
do for [i=0:(num_tics-1)] {
    set y2tics add (f(Y0+i*DY))
    set y2tics add ('' f(Y0+(i+0.5)*DY) 1)
}

set terminal pop # restore terminal
replot
```

Comment: thanks again, i hoped for a better solution that is independent of range but it will work thanks

Comment: @vlad_tepesch You can make it independent on the actual range, but must known the number of tics. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **integer** xtics are mapped by default to x2tics.

The following snippet is modified from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52121541/11769765
[image]

```
set tics nomirror
set x2tics
set link x2 via x**2 inv sqrt(x)
plot sin(x)
```

However, decimal values are not mapped, as one sees when zooming in:
[image]