# gnuplot: set link and x2tics in interactive mode

Tags: gnuplot

In interactive mode, the x2tics are disappearing soon when zooming in.

This example was shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60373156/11769765)

```
set tics nomirror
set x2tics
set link x2 via x**2 inv sqrt(x)
plot sin(x)
```

[image][image]

I would like to have at least an orientation, and don't care whether the x2tics are placed equidistant or mapped  from the xtics.

A manual `set x2tics 1` gives a nice static results.

[image]

But is there a solution for interactive mode?

Edit:

This clumpy possibility requires to press 'a' to update the plot each time:

```
bind a "set x2tics (GPVAL_X2_MAX-GPVAL_X2_MIN)/5; replot"
```

or for a bit more round steps (1,2,5)

```
bind a "dx2 = (GPVAL_X2_MAX-GPVAL_X2_MIN) / 5;\
        i10 = 10 ** floor(log10(dx2));\
        f10 = dx2 / i10;\
        set x2tics i10*(f10<1.5?1:f10<4?2:5);\
        replot"
```

Answer (score 0):

One can employ a dummy function, which samples new positions on the fly and uses the `x2ticlabels` specifier (see `help xticlabels`)

```
set tics nomirror
set x2tics
set link x2
plot sin(x)  # to preset GPVAL_X_MIN and GPVAL_X_MAX
plot sin(x), [t=GPVAL_X_MIN:GPVAL_X_MAX:(GPVAL_X_MAX-GPVAL_X_MIN)/5] "+" us (t):(NaN):x2tic(sprintf("%g",sqrt(t)))
```

For rectangle zooom this still needs a `replot` event, while for wheel-zoom it works smoothly.