# Linked top x-axis in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

My `test.dat` file is given below

```
6.78E-01    -1.907881356    -1.938152542    -1.994762712    -4.409491525    -3.707118644    -2.623559322    -1.903389831    -1.891452492    -1.880469492    -2.009079661    -1.835169492    -2.193627119
6.73E-01    -1.828333333    -1.861727273    -1.916205387    -4.308956229    -3.614276094    -2.547508418    -1.823097643    -1.811922731    -1.800939731    -1.930919529    -1.757255892    -2.114855219
6.69E-01    -1.749849498    -1.786324415    -1.838698997    -4.209765886    -3.522675585    -2.472474916    -1.743879599    -1.733456913    -1.722473913    -1.853805017    -1.680384615    -2.037137124
6.64E-01    -1.672408638    -1.711923588    -1.762222591    -4.111893688    -3.432292359    -2.398438538    -1.665714286    -1.656033831    -1.645050831    -1.777715282    -1.604534884    -1.960451827
6.60E-01    -1.595990099    -1.63850495     -1.686755776    -4.015313531    -3.34310231     -2.325379538    -1.588580858    -1.579632835    -1.568649835    -1.702630033    -1.529686469    -1.884778878
6.56E-01    -1.52057377     -1.56604918     -1.612278689    -3.92           -3.255081967    -2.253278689    -1.512459016    -1.50423382     -1.49325082     -1.628529508    -1.455819672    -1.810098361
6.51E-01    -1.446140065    -1.494537459    -1.538771987    -3.825928339    -3.168208469    -2.182117264    -1.43732899     -1.429817202    -1.418834202    -1.555394463    -1.382915309    -1.736390879
6.47E-01    -1.372669903    -1.423951456    -1.466216828    -3.733074434    -3.082459547    -2.111877023    -1.363171521    -1.356363906    -1.345380906    -1.483206149    -1.310954693    -1.66363754
6.43E-01    -1.300144695    -1.354273312    -1.394594855    -3.641414791    -2.997813505    -2.042540193    -1.289967846    -1.283855347    -1.272872347    -1.411946302    -1.239919614    -1.591819936
6.39E-01    -1.228546326    -1.285485623    -1.323888179    -3.550926518    -2.914249201    -1.974089457    -1.217699681    -1.212273415    -1.201290415    -1.341597125    -1.169792332    -1.520920128
6.35E-01    -1.157857143    -1.217571429    -1.254079365    -3.461587302    -2.831746032    -1.906507937    -1.146349206    -1.14160046     -1.13061746     -1.27214127     -1.100555556    -1.450920635
6.31E-01    -1.088059937    -1.150514196    -1.18515142     -3.373375394    -2.750283912    -1.83977918     -1.075899054    -1.071819278    -1.060836278    -1.20356183     -1.032192429    -1.381804416
6.27E-01    -1.019137931    -1.084297806    -1.117087774    -3.286269592    -2.66984326     -1.773887147    -1.006332288    -1.002913094    -0.991930094    -1.13584232     -0.96468652     -1.313554859
6.23E-01    -0.951074766    -1.018906542    -1.049872274    -3.200249221    -2.590404984    -1.708816199    -0.937632399    -0.934865555    -0.923882555    -1.068966667    -0.898021807    -1.246155763
6.19E-01    -0.883854489    -0.954325077    -0.983489164    -3.115294118    -2.511950464    -1.644551084    -0.869783282    -0.867660709    -0.856677709    -1.002919195    -0.832182663    -1.179591331
6.15E-01    -0.817461538    -0.890538462    -0.917923077    -3.031384615    -2.434461538    -1.581076923    -0.802769231    -0.801283       -0.7903         -0.937684615    -0.767153846    -1.113846154
6.12E-01    -0.751880734    -0.82753211     -0.853159021    -2.948501529    -2.357920489    -1.518379205    -0.736574924    -0.735717251    -0.724734251    -0.873248012    -0.702920489    -1.048905199
6.08E-01    -0.687097264    -0.765291793    -0.789182371    -2.86662614     -2.28231003     -1.456443769    -0.67118541     -0.670948653    -0.659965653    -0.809594833    -0.639468085    -0.984753799
6.04E-01    -0.623096677    -0.703803625    -0.725978852    -2.785740181    -2.207613293    -1.395256798    -0.606586103    -0.606962758    -0.595979758    -0.746710876    -0.576782477    -0.921377644
```

I use the following code in gnuplot to check the plot

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced colour font 'Times-Roman,12' size 6in,5in  
set output "Plot1.eps"


set xtics out scale 1.5 
set ytics out scale 1.5
set tics font ", 16"
set xlabel "10^{3}{/Symbol \264} 1/T (K^{-1})" font ",16"
set ylabel "log&{t}{/Times-Italic p}_{Pu({/Times-Italic g}),Pa} " font ",16"
set key outside right top 
set key maxrows 12 spacing 2.1 font ",16" width -2

plot [0.60:0.70] 'test.dat.dat' u 1:2 with points pt 1 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" title "Maeda {/Times-Italic et al.} [7]", \
'' u 1:3 with points pt 1 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" title "Pu-20Zr [7]", \
'' u 1:4 with points pt 1 ps 1.75 lt rgb "dark-green" title "Pu-50Zr [7]", \
'' u 1:5 with points pt 2 ps 1.75 lt -1 title "Present work", \
'' u 1:6 with points pt 3 ps 1.75 lt -1 title "Present work", \
'' u 1:7 with points pt 4 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" title "Alcock [16]", \
'' u 1:8 with points pt 4 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" title "Phipps {/Times-Italic et al.} [19]", \
'' u 1:9 with points pt 4 ps 1.75 lt rgb "dark-green" title "Mulford [20]", \
'' u 1:10 with points pt 5 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" title "Kent [21]", \
'' u 1:11 with points pt 5 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" title "Ackermann and Rauh [22]", \
'' u 1:12 with points pt 5 ps 1.75 lt rgb "dark-green" title "Bradbury and Ohse [23]", \
'' u 1:13 with points pt 5 ps 1.75 lt -1 title "Kim and Hofman [24]"
```

The code runs well. One can see that `x axis` is related to temperature as `1000/temperature`. Now I wanted a linked top `x2-axis` with temperature in K. So, for example, `xrange` is from 0.6 to 0.7. Then `x2 axis` should be from 1000/0.6 to 1000/0.7 i.e. from 1666.67  K to 1428.57 K. So I modified the code based on `linkedaxes.dem`.

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced colour font 'Times-Roman,12' size 6in,5in  
set output "Plot2.eps"


set xtics out scale 1.5 
set ytics out scale 1.5
set tics font ", 16"
set xtics nomirror 
set xlabel "10^{3}{/Symbol \264} 1/T (K^{-1})" font ",16"
set ylabel "log&{t}{/Times-Italic p}_{Pu({/Times-Italic g}),Pa} " font ",16"
set key outside right top 
set key maxrows 12 spacing 2.1 font ",16" width -2
set link x2 via 1000./x inverse 1000./x
set x2tics out scale 1.5 
set x2label "Temperature (K)" font ",16"


plot [0.60:0.70] 'test.dat' u 1:2 with points pt 1 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" title "Maeda {/Times-Italic et al.} [7]", \
'' u 1:3 with points pt 1 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" title "Pu-20Zr [7]", \
'' u 1:4 with points pt 1 ps 1.75 lt rgb "dark-green" title "Pu-50Zr [7]", \
'' u 1:5 with points pt 2 ps 1.75 lt -1 title "Present work ", \
'' u 1:6 with points pt 3 ps 1.75 lt -1 title "Present work", \
'' u 1:7 with points pt 4 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" title "Alcock [16]", \
'' u 1:8 with points pt 4 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" title "Phipps {/Times-Italic et al.} [19]", \
'' u 1:9 with points pt 4 ps 1.75 lt rgb "dark-green" title "Mulford [20]", \
'' u 1:10 with points pt 5 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" title "Kent [21]", \
'' u 1:11 with points pt 5 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" title "Ackermann and Rauh [22]", \
'' u 1:12 with points pt 5 ps 1.75 lt rgb "dark-green" title "Bradbury and Ohse [23]", \
'' u 1:13 with points pt 5 ps 1.75 lt -1 title "Kim and Hofman [24]"
```

But the `set link` does not give the computed values on the top `x2 axis`. What modifications in code need to be made?

Comment: I posted a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60373827/gnuplot-set-link-and-x2tics-in-interactive-mode. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like for some reason (which I don't know) you have to give an increment for the x2tics.
Try the following minimal example:

**Code:**

```
### link x2 axis
reset session

set xrange[0.6:0.7]
set xtics nomirror

set link x2 via 1000./x inverse 1000./x
set x2tics 50

plot x
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]